# How do I check the character set used by ubuntu and probably change it

Tags: character-set

As the subject says, I am curious to know what character-set is used by Ubuntu, is it ASCII or something else like utf-8/utf-16 etc. And  if possible how can i change the default character set.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need but check out system settings / keyboard layout. Here you can change the key set by country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Locales customize programs to your language and country. When you
>   installed Ubuntu, you answered some simple questions such as
>   specifying your country and language. Ubuntu used the answers to those
>   questions, in part, to choose a suitable locale for your installation.
>
> The basic functionality is provided by the locale package, which is
>   installed by default. Actual locales are installed separately via the
>   language-pack-* packages.

[image]

> Most users want a single locale to be used for all aspects of their
>   session. In this case, the GUI provided by System Settings -> Language
>   Support does the right thing.
>
> Below are some of the things that you can do:
>
> - List installed locales
> - List current settings
> - Changing settings temporarily
> - Changing settings permanently
> - (Re-)Generating locales<sup>1</sup>

[Read On](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/)</sup>